# Stuck on using postRenderers patchesStrategicMerge on a HelmRelease

Tags: kubernetes

So I'm working on a Flux config and I have successfully deployed a HelmRelease. Now I want to patch it. But I'm not sure I understand how this patch format works. This is my current config (without postRenderers I don't get the error):

```yaml
apiVersion: 
kind: HelmRelease
metadata:
  name: ${elasticsearch_flx_app_name}
  namespace: ${elasticsearch_flx_app_name}
spec:
  interval: 1m
  install:
    disableWait: true
  upgrade:
    disableWait: true
  chart:
    spec:
      chart: search-guard-flx
      version: "2.5.0"
      sourceRef:
        kind: HelmRepository
        name: my-oci
        namespace: flux-system
  postRenderers:
    - kustomize:
        patchesStrategicMerge:
          - apiVersion: apps/v1
            kind: StatefulSet
            metadata:
              namespace: ${elasticsearch_flx_app_name}
              labels:
                app: ${elasticsearch_flx_app_name}-${cluster_env}
                test_label: foo
  values:
    # ... values omitted for brevity
```

The error I get is this:

```
preparing upgrade for elasticsearch-flx                                                                                                                                                                 
resetting values to the chart's original version                                                                                                                                                             
  Warning  error  55s (x4 over 29m)  helm-controller  reconciliation failed: Helm upgrade failed: error while running post render on files: trouble configuring builtin PatchStrategicMergeTransformer with c
onfig: `                                                                                                                                                                                                     
paths:                                                                                                                                                                                                       
- '{"apiVersion":"apps/v1","kind":"StatefulSet","metadata":{"labels":{"app":"elasticsearch-flx-dev","test_label":"foo"},"namespace":"elasticsearch-flx"}}'                                         
`: '/{"apiVersion":"apps/v1","kind":"StatefulSet","metadata":{"labels":{"app":"elasticsearch-flx-dev","test_label":"foo"},"namespace":"elasticsearch-flx"}}' doesn't exist
```

I interpret my patch to mean "find a statefulset in this namespace and this app label and add test_label: foo". But it feels a bit weird to mix selector with modification in inline patch. I'm probably missunderstanding?